# Hide password in Post action - MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a form with username and password field in my view,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder ="Username"  })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                        Sign in
                    </button> 
                 }
```

I have a viewmodel for my login,

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required, AllowHtml]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

In my post method for submit button in the controller,

When I use the breakpoint in my controller, I can view the password, see the snapshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXhaO.png)

Is there a way that I can make it invisible or dotted or hashed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why bother? If someone has gotten to the point where they've managed to attach a debugger to your application, they can do anything they want.

Comment: Yeah, But is there a way i can encrypt while sending from view to controller.

Comment: For what purpose? If they can attach a debugger to the system they can probably just decrypt it.

Comment: Why do you want to allow the user to enter html content into the username & password field?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a HTTPS page? It's encrypted on post..